# Flash - Adding objects to a scene randomly, at certain set points

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm in the process of creating a simple Flash game using ActionScript 3.0 and have come across an issue when spawning my obstacles onto the scene. My aim is to have approximately 10 points across the x axis (remaining at the same y axis) and when spawning the obstacles into my scene it will pick 2-4 of those points randomly and spawn them on them.

I've got the obstacles to spawn randomly but cannot figure out how to make them spawn at random set points, from a list. If anyone could help, I would be much appreciative. Thanks

**EDIT:**

The code I have so far:

```
var a:Array = new Array();
for (var count=0; count< 5; count++) {
        a[count] = new asteroidOne();
        a[count].x = 100 * count + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 200));
        a[count].y = 100;
        addChild(a[count]);
}

// Asteroid obstacle spawning 2.0

player.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, obstacleMove);
function obstacleMove(evt:Event):void {
        for (var i=0; i< 5; i++) {
                a[i].y += 5;
                if (a[i].y == 480) {
                        a[i].y = 0;    
                }
                if (player.hitTestObject(a[i])) {
                        trace("HIT");
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code where you have the problem?

Comment: It's not really a problem I have of the code I'm writing to do it, because I don't know how to do that thing specifically. I've edited my first post to include the code I have so far though.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish?  You have a loop that creates 5 asteroids and stuffs them into an array, and set their x to be a random value. Then every frame you move them down 5 pixels.  What else are you trying to do?   Are you trying to make the starting astroid x not totally random but instead a value from a list of acceptable x starting points?

Comment: If so,  just create an array/vector of all the acceptable starting points, randomize it, and pop the array every iteration on your astroid creation loop.  I'll post an example tomorrow if still needed.

Comment: How would I go about that then? I'm still a little new to this and so I'm not quite sure how to have it randomly pick from it. An example would be incredibly helpful please! Thank you! @LDMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have your spawn points in an array, you could do the following:

```
var spawnPoints:Array = [100,200,250,300,450,500,600,800]; //your list of spawn x locations
spawnPoints.sort(randomizeArray); //lets randomize the spwanPoints

function randomizeArray(a:*, b:*):int {
    return ( Math.random() < .5 ) ? 1 : -1;
}

var a:Vector.<asteroidOne> = new Vector.<asteroidOne>(); //the array for your astroids - changed to vector for possible performance and code hint improvement (basically the same as Array but every object has to be of the specified type)

for (var count:int=0; count < 5; count++) {
        a.push(new asteroidOne());
        a[count].x = spawnPoints.pop(); //pop removes the last element from the array and returns it
        a[count].y = 100;
        addChild(a[count]);
}
```

---

### EDIT

To address you comments, here is a decent example:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;

var spawnTimer:Timer = new Timer(10000); //timer will tick every 10 seconds
spawnTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, spawn, false, 0, true); //let's run the spawn function every timer tick
spawnTimer.start();

var spawnPoints:Array = [100,200,250,300,450,500,600,800]; //your list of spawn x locations
var spawnAmount:int = 5; //how many asteroids to have on the screen at once (you could increase this over time to make it more difficult)
var asteroids:Vector.<asteroidOne> = new Vector.<asteroidOne>(); //the array for your asteroids - changed to vector for possible performance and code hint improvement (basically the same as Array but every object has to be of the specified type)

spawn(); //lets call it right away (otherwise it will won't be called until the first timer tick in 10 seconds)

//calling this will spawn as many new asteroids as are needed to reach the given amount
function spawn(e:Event = null):void {
    if(asteroids.length >= spawnAmount) return; //let's not bother running any of the code below if no new asteroids are needed
    spawnPoints.sort(randomizeArray); //lets randomize the spwanPoints
    var spawnIndex:int = 0;

    var a:asteroidOne; //var to hold the asteroid every loop
    while (asteroids.length < spawnAmount) {
        a = new asteroidOne();
        a.x = spawnPoints[spawnIndex];
        spawnIndex++; //incriment the spawn index
        if (spawnIndex >= spawnPoints.length) spawnIndex = 0; //if the index is out of range of the amount of items in the array, go back to the start

        a.y = 100;
        asteroids.push(a); //add it to the array/vector
        addChild(a); //add it to the display 
    }
}

player.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, obstacleMove);
function obstacleMove(evt:Event):void {

    //this is the same as a backwards for loop - for(var i:int=asteroids.length-1;i >= 0; i--)
    var i:int = asteroids.length;
    while(i--){  //since we are potentially removing items from the array/vector, we need to iterate backwards - otherwise when you remove an item, the indices will have shifted and you'll eventually get an out of range error
        asteroids[i].y += 5;
        if (asteroids[i].y > stage.stageHeight || asteroids[i].x > stage.stageWidth || asteroids[i].x < -asteroids[i].width || asteroids[i].y < -asteroids[i].height) {
            //object is out of the bounds of the stage, let's remove it

            removeChild(asteroids[i]); //remove it from the display
            asteroids.splice(i, 1); //remove it from the array/vector

            continue; //move on to the next iteration in the for loop
        }

        if (player.hitTestObject(asteroids[i])) {
            trace("HIT");
        }
    }
}

function randomizeArray(a:*, b:*):int {
    return ( Math.random() < .5 ) ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Comment: Wow, that looks complicated. I'll give it a shot in a little while and see how it works with my code. Thank you so much and I'll let you know if I encounter any issues!

Comment: Awesome, it works! Thank you so much @LDMS Now I just need to get it to spawn new ones every few seconds and delete them when they go off screen, which should be fairly easy. Would I be right in assuming that I can just put it in a loop to run this every "x" seconds whilst a condition is true?

Comment: you most definitely do not want to use a for loop to run code over time - use a timer for that.   I'll add a couple examples to the answer to get you going.

Comment: Sorry, still a little new to the site. I've accepted the answer and I'm looking through your new example now. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Right, I've added that example into my code and it doesn't seem to add the asteroids to the scene? I've checked to make sure everything is referenced properly but it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: They do spawn after 10 seconds, my mistake. However once they reach the bottom of the scene, I get this error:

RangeError: Error #1125: The index 2 is out of range 2.
 at _8_fla::MainTimeline/obstacleMove()
ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
 at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
 at _8_fla::MainTimeline/obstacleMove()
RangeError: Error #1125: The index 0 is out of range 0.
 at _8_fla::MainTimeline/obstacleMove()

Not really sure what's up with it

Comment: Updated my code and they now spawn immediately, but I still get that error in the output

Comment: So I move the astroids.splice(i, 1) after the if (player.hitTestObject(astroids[i])) {
            trace("HIT");
        } ?

Comment: Yay, it works now! Thank you so much! I do have one last query though, is it possible to have it so the limit on asteroids isn't for each row? As in it has a limit of 6, but spawns 3 on one row and then 3 on the next?

Comment: just repeat the x coordinates of the spawn point that should have more in the array (the more occurrences in the array, the more likely it will spawn from there)

Comment: No no, I mean so instead of having all it so only one row can be on the scene at a time, is it possible to have two? The maximum spawnAmount would be split on those two rows?

Comment: I'd also greatly appreciate it if you could maybe take a look at my other issue that I have? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26946768/detecting-and-using-collision-detection-between-two-different-arrays-to-remove-i