# Detecting and using collision detection between two different arrays to remove instances of them

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, collision-detection

I'm currently creating a small flash game using ActionScript and after receiving help for another issue I had on here, I've encountered another one when moving onto a different part of it.

This is the code I currently have:

```
var asteroidSpeed = 5;
var soundExplosion:Sound = new ExplosionSound();
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKDown);

var newLaser:Array = new Array();

function onKDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
            /*laser.x = player.x + player.width/2 - laser.width/2;
            laser.y = player.y;
            addChild(laser);*/
            for (var count=0; count < 4; count++) {
                    newLaser[count] = new shipLaser();
                    newLaser[count].x = player.x + player.width/2 - newLaser.width/2;
                    newLaser[count].y = player.y;
                    addChild(newLaser[count]);
            }
    }
}

var spawnTimer:Timer = new Timer(3000); //timer will tick every 3 seconds
spawnTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, spawn, false, 0, true); //let's run the spawn function every timer tick
spawnTimer.start();

var spawnPoints:Array = [0,100,200,300,400,500,550]; //your list of spawn x locations
var spawnAmount:int = 4; //how many asteroids to have on the screen at once (you could increase this over time to make it more difficult)
var asteroids:Vector.<asteroidOne> = new Vector.<asteroidOne>(); //the array for your asteroids - changed to vector for possible performance and code hint improvement (basically the same as Array but every object has to be of the specified type)

spawn(); // calling it immediately

//calling this will spawn as many new asteroids as are needed to reach the given amount
function spawn(e:Event = null):void {
if(asteroids.length >= spawnAmount) return; //let's not bother running any of the code below if     no new asteroids are needed
spawnPoints.sort(randomizeArray); //lets randomize the spwanPoints
var spawnIndex:int = 0;

var a:asteroidOne; //var to hold the asteroid every loop
while (asteroids.length < spawnAmount) {
    a = new asteroidOne();
    a.x = spawnPoints[spawnIndex];
    spawnIndex++; //incriment the spawn index
    if (spawnIndex >= spawnPoints.length) spawnIndex = 0; //if the index is out of range of the amount of items in the array, go back to the start

    a.y = -50;
    asteroids.push(a); //add it to the array/vector
    addChild(a); //add it to the display
}
}

player.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, obstacleMove);
function obstacleMove(evt:Event):void {
for (var i:int = 0; i < asteroids.length;i++) {
    asteroids[i].y += asteroidSpeed;
    if (asteroids[i].y > stage.stageHeight || asteroids[i].x > stage.stageWidth || asteroids[i].x < -asteroids[i].width || asteroids[i].y < -asteroids[i].height) {
        //object is out of the bounds of the stage, let's remove it

                    removeChild(asteroids[i]); //remove it from the display
        asteroids.splice(i, 1); //remove it from the array/vector

                    continue; //move on to the next iteration in the for loop
    }

    if (player.hitTestObject(asteroids[i])) {
        trace("HIT");
                    removeChild(asteroids[i]);
                    asteroids.splice(i,1);
                    removeChild(player);
                    // will add end-game trigger here soon.
    }
}
}

function randomizeArray(a:*, b:*):int {
return (Math.random() < .5 ) ? 1 : -1;
}

player.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, laserCollision);
function laserCollision(evt:Event):void {
    for (var i in newLaser) {
            for (var a in asteroids) {
                    if (asteroids[a].hitTestObject(newLaser[i])) {
                            trace("BOOM!");
                            var soundExplosion:Sound = new ExplosionSound();
                            var channel1:SoundChannel = soundExplosion.play();
                            removeChild(newLaser[i]);
                            removeChild(asteroids[a]);
                    }
            }
    }
}

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, laserEnter);

function laserEnter(event:Event):void {
    for (var i in newLaser) {
            newLaser[i].y -= laserSpeed;
    // Moves the laser up the screen
            if(newLaser[i].y == 0) {
                    removeChild(newLaser[i]);
            }
    }
}
```

What I want to do is when an instance from the newLaser array collides with an instance of the asteroids array, to remove both from the scene / indexes (but only the two that collided and not all of the ones on the scene).

Currently, when a laser hits an asteroid, it removes the asteroid but not the laser and one of the asteroids on the current row stops moving and then the next row of asteroids spawns but does not move down.

I get this error too:

ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
    at _8_fla::MainTimeline/obstacleMove()

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are so many things wrong with this code. You really need to look at each line and realize exactly what is happening, and decide whether that code is correct or needs changing. I'll start you off with your onKDown function. You basically create 4 new lasers on top of each other every time the button is pressed. And then every time a new laser is fired you lose reference to the previous one by overwriting the newLaser array. Stuff like this is gonna cause you all kinds of headaches and errors.

Comment: I've looked at my code and because I'm still quite new at this, I can't see what's wrong which is what my issue is. I used the code to spawn the lasers in an earlier section for my initial testing of the asteroids. It spawned four asteroids at different times. I'm really not sure :S @Karma

Comment: What is the point of having 4 lasers at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You error, is likely because you are running 3 separate enter frame handlers in the same scope, and removing items from arrays and display lists (that are referenced in multiple enter frame handlers).  So you asteroid is removed from the display list in one, and then you try to remove it again in another.

There are also a whole lot of other issues with your code that will cause errors and undesired results. Things like `for(var i in newLasers)` - in that kind of loop, `i` will refer to the actual laser object not the index of the array. I've re-factored your code and added lots of code comments to **hopefully** give you an idea of where you were going wrong:

```
var spawnTimer:Timer = new Timer(3000); //timer will tick every 3 seconds
var spawnPoints:Array = [0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 550]; //your list of spawn x locations
var spawnAmount:int = 4; //how many asteroids to have on the screen at once (you could increase this over time to make it more difficult)

var asteroidSpeed = 5;
var asteroids:Vector.<asteroidOne> = new Vector.<asteroidOne>(); //the array for your asteroids - changed to vector for possible performance and code hint improvement (basically the same as Array but every object has to be of the specified type)

var lasers:Vector.<shipLaser> = new shipLaser(); //the array of lasers
var maxLasers:int = 4; //the maximum amount lasers allowed at any given time

var soundExplosion:Sound = new ExplosionSound();

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKDown);
player.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoop);
spawnTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, spawn, false, 0, true); //let's run the spawn function every timer tick
spawnTimer.start(); //start the spawn timer
spawn(); // calling it immediately


function onKDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
        //create ONE laser per button push (instead of 4 identical lasers)

        if(lasers.length < maxLasers){ //if player hasn't reached the maximum amount of lasers available
            var tmpLaser:shipLaser = new shipLaser();
            tmpLaser.x = player.x + player.width / 2 - tmpLaser.width / 2;
            tmpLaser.y = player.y;
            addChild(tmpLaser);
            lasers.push(tmpLaser);
        }
    }
}

//calling this will spawn as many new asteroids as are needed to reach the given amount
function spawn(e:Event = null):void {
    if (asteroids.length >= spawnAmount)
        return; //let's not bother running any of the code below if no new asteroids are needed

    spawnPoints.sort(randomizeArray); //lets randomize the spwanPoints
    var spawnIndex:int = 0;

    var a:asteroidOne; //var to hold the asteroid every loop
    while (asteroids.length < spawnAmount)
    {
        a = new asteroidOne();
        a.x = spawnPoints[spawnIndex];
        spawnIndex++; //incriment the spawn index
        if (spawnIndex >= spawnPoints.length)
            spawnIndex = 0; //if the index is out of range of the amount of items in the array, go back to the start

        a.y = -50;
        asteroids.push(a); //add it to the array/vector
        addChild(a); //add it to the display
    }
}

function gameLoop(e:Event):void {
    //LOOP through all the asteroids, give it a label (asteroidLoop) so we can break/continue it inside other loops
    asteroidLoop: for (var i:int = 0; i < asteroids.length; i++) {

        //check if asteroid is out of bounds
        if (asteroids[i].y > stage.stageHeight || asteroids[i].x > stage.stageWidth || asteroids[i].x < -asteroids[i].width || asteroids[i].y < -asteroids[i].height) {
            //object is out of the bounds of the stage, let's remove it

            removeChild(asteroids[i]); //remove it from the display
            asteroids.splice(i, 1); //remove it from the array/vector

            continue; //forget the rest of the code below and move on to the next iteration in the for loop since the asteroid is gone 
        }

        //check if any lasers are colliding with this asteroid
        for (var j:int = lasers.length-1; j >= 0;j--) { //iterate over all lasers backwards
            if (asteroids[i].hitTestObject(lasers[j])){
                trace("BOOM!");
                var soundExplosion:Sound = new ExplosionSound();
                var channel1:SoundChannel = soundExplosion.play();

                //remove the asteroid
                removeChild(asteroids[i]); //remove it from the display
                asteroids.splice(i, 1); //remove it from the array/vector

                //remove the laser
                removeChild(lasers[j]);
                lasers.splice(j, 1);

                continue asteroidLoop; //break completely out of this inner for-loop (lasers) since the asteroid in the outer loop was removed, and move on to the next asteroid
            }
        }

        //check if this asteroid collides with the player
        if (player.hitTestObject(asteroids[i])){
            trace("HIT");

            //remove the asteroid
            removeChild(asteroids[i]); //remove it from the display
            asteroids.splice(i, 1); //remove it from the array/vector

            removeChild(player);

            spawnTimer.stop(); //stop spawning new asteroids

            //will add end-game trigger here soon.

            break; //break completely out of the asteroid loop if it's game over (as there's no point in checking the rest of the asteroids)

        }

        //we've made it this far, so let's just move this asteroid
        asteroids[i].y += asteroidSpeed;
    }


    for (var i:int = lasers.length-1; i >= 0;i--) { //iterate backwards
        lasers[i].y -= laserSpeed;
        // Moves the laser up the screen
        if (lasers[i].y <= 0){ //make this less than or equal to 0
            removeChild(lasers[i]); //remove the laser from the display list
            lasers.splice(i, 1); //remove the laser from the array
        }
    }
}

function randomizeArray(a:*, b:*):int {
    return (Math.random() < .5) ? 1 : -1;
}
```